# Split a string using a list of value at the same time

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

I have a string and a list:

```
src = 'ways to learn are read and execute.'
temp = ['ways to','are','and']
```

What I wanted is to split the string using the list `temp`'s values and produce:

```
['learn','read','execute']
```

at the same time.

I had tried `for` loop:

```
for x in temp:
    src.split(x)
```

This is what it produced:

```
['','to learn are read and execute.']
['ways to learn','read and execute.']
['ways to learn are read','execute.']
```

What I wanted is to output all the values in list first, then use it split the string.

Did anyone has solutions?

Comment: Why does the desired output not include a dot at the end of `'execute'`?

Comment: @timgeb Thanks for the reminder, actually the dot also not what I wanted. I forgot to specify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`re.split` is the conventional solution for splitting on multiple separators:

```
import re

src = 'ways to learn are read and execute.'
temp = ['ways to','are','and']

pattern = "|".join(re.escape(item) for item in temp)
result = re.split(pattern, src)
print(result)
```

Result:

```
['', ' learn ', ' read ', ' execute.']
```

You can also filter out blank items and strip the spaces+punctuation with a simple list comprehension:

```
result = [item.strip(" .") for item in result if item]
print(result)
```

Result:

```
['learn', 'read', 'execute']
```

Comment: Nitpick: This may split words if they contain one of the `temp` elements.

Comment: @tobias_k Hmm, true. If that's undesirable behavior, perhaps you could use word boundaries in the pattern: `pattern = "|".join("\\b" + re.escape(item) + "\\b" for item in temp)`

Comment: I'd say that's up to `temp` to decide. If you want word-boundaries, use the `\b`s in `temp`.

Comment: Might also want: `pattern = "|".join(re.escape(item) for item in sorted(temp, key=len, reverse=True))` to split on longest complete patterns first...

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for the answer. Right now I understand how it works, did you add `|` to turn the list into a string and tells the `re.split()` to split using all or any of the values in the list `temp`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a method which is purely pythonic and does not rely on regular expressions. It's more verbose and more complex:

```
result = []
current = 0
for part in temp:
    too_long_result = src.split(part)[1]
    if current + 1 < len(temp): result.append(too_long_result.split(temp[current+1])[0].lstrip().rstrip())
    else: result.append(too_long_result.lstrip().rstrip())
    current += 1
print(result)
```

You cann remove the `.lstrip().rstrip()` commands if you don't want to remove the trailing and leading whitespaces in the list entries.

Answer (score 0):

Loop solution. You can add conditions such as strip if you need them.

```
src = 'ways to learn are read and execute.'
temp = ['ways to','are','and']
copy_src = src
result = []
for x in temp:
    left, right = copy_src.split(x)
    if left:
        result.append(left) #or left.strip()
    copy_src = right
result.append(copy_src) #or copy_src.strip()
```

Comment: This fails if `x` appears more or less than exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

just keep it simple

```
src = 'ways to learn are read and execute.'
temp = ['ways','to','are','and']
res=''
for w1 in src.split():
  if w1 not in temp:
    if w1 not in res.split():
      res=res+w1+" "
 print(res)
```

Comment: This does not really do what OP asked for, discardings "ways" and "to" and not just "ways to", removing duplicates and joining the rest back to one string. Also, rather inefficient. At least make `temp` a `set` and if you want to have unique words, also use a `set` for `res` and then `' '.join` at the end.